# Modifying the background color of a day with an event in Fullcalendar plugin

Tags: events, colors, calendar, fullcalendar

I need to change the background color of a specific day which has an event added through the Google Calendar.

I removed the way it originally shows an event, as you might know, just like in Calendar, because I don't need that.

I've also thought in a way to add in the source code a condition to check if there's an event in that day, and if the condition is true, add a special class such fc-has-event, and then modify it through CSS rule. But the problem is that I have no idea how I could do it, I've already spent two days checking the code.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Can you provided some code of what you have already done?

Comment: I guess this wouldn't be necessary. I actually didn't change anything in the source code, because I simply couldn't figure it out how to do it.
All I've changed so far was in the CSS file to make it look like how I need it. :(

Answer (score 0):

Inside [`eventRender`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) use the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor to compare the event date with a manual set date:

```javascript
var google_date = new Date( event._start._d );
var check_date = new Date( '2014-09-09' ); // The date you want to highlight
if ( google_date.toDateString() == check_date.toDateString() ) {
   element.addClass( 'custom-class' );
}
```